# Apache2 webserver not displaying pages

Tags: linux, apache, apache2

I have this strange problem that happens whenever I go to visit any of my websites hosted on my Apache2 server.  When I visit a site, chrome just downloads this file named 'download' and just displays a blank page.  I opened the the file named 'download' in notepad++ and it displays the html source code to the website.  Anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misconfigured your server: it's returning the wrong mime-type. Go find the config which came with your Apache installation and compare it with the current state to find the stuff which is broken.

Comment: Thank you.  Managed to fix it.